# Is it possible to create a new String from a subset of another String without any data copy?

Tags: java, string

I had (apparenty an incorrect?) impression that Java substring(srcArray, startIndex, endIndex) method did not allocate new memory but instead re-used the existing underlying char[] array.  This approach would seem to be possible due to the immutability of String's.

However when actually looking at the JDK source we find the following:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {

    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}

public String(char value[], int offset, int count) {


    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);

}
```

Notice the `copyOfRange()` which copies/duplicates the content.

The motivation for this was working with very large arrays representing the backing store of matrices for linear algebra. There is NO way we are going to accept copying them.  I would like however to have a custom representation of portions of the backing array for convenience in programming. It would however only be reasonable if no data copy were to be performed.  The tie-in with String is that I looked into how the String handles no-data-copy and found that they (in later java versions apparently..) do actually perform the copy.

So, is there actually any way to achieve the zero-copy?

Comment: It's an implementation detail whether the data is copied or simply referenced in the source string.  There are performance advantages/disadvantages to both schemes.  I'm wondering why you think you care, since the choice is a matter of "tuning" on the part of the JVM designers and is strongly linked to the garbage collector algorithms.

Comment: @HotLicks  Added motivation info.

Comment: Is this data character data, numeric data, or "bytes"?  You should only use String for data that is in character form.

Comment: @HotLicks  I noted the tie-in to String in the last sentence of the motivation paragraph. Strings are not being used to represent other data types - instead I wanted to see how String does the zero copy in order to apply to other data types

Comment: Then simply get a copy of the old String code.  But be warned that that particular implementation is a bit convoluted.  But the basic concept is simple:  An array reference, an offset value, and a length value.  If you "define" that the array is never modified then you can "share" it with impunity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It *used* to be that way, but it was changed; the designers of Java came to the conclusion that it caused more problems than it solved, specifically due to a) the risk of memory leaks, b) the fact that most `substring` calls are for relatively small ranges that are cheap to copy.

The closest thing you can do, to get a `CharSequence` view of a subrange of the `String` without copying, you can do by writing `CharBuffer.wrap(string).subSequence(from, to)`.

Comment: btw is there a similar construct to CharBuffer.wrap for general arrays? I looked at Buffer (the superclass) and did not find one.

Comment: What do you mean, general arrays?  There are different buffer types for each of the primitive types.  If you want to wrap an object array, use `Arrays.asList` to view it as a `List`.

Comment: For the other primitive types, you can use the `slice()` methods of their corresponding buffers.

Comment: To be specific: double[].  Using Arrays.asList would involve data copying/object creation which I want to avoid.

Comment: For more information (for those interested) here is a link to [Java-Performance.info](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) giving an overview of the change and here is a link to a [Reddit post from an Oracle dev](http://www.reddit.com/comments/1qw73v) talking more in depth about the technical details.

Comment: Sounds like you want `DoubleBuffer.slice()`, or you could just use `DoubleBuffer.wrap(array, offset, length)` possibly.

Comment: @LouisWasserman  Yes!!  Please make this an answer.  Actually I probably should have created two questions - the second specifcally about Double and you get awarded both.  I may do that ..

Comment: @MikeKobit  If you would like to make an answer out of your comment I would at least upvote it for being quite useful (Louis has provided a great answer and I awarded it)

Comment: But, think of String.split(), it is not supported by CharBuffer. The splited string[] should be nice to share the original string.value, instead of copy data. So I'm looking forward on a  no-copy substring String implementation in the future JDK!

Comment: @neoedmund  Unfortunately it's the other way around: the no-copy was _removed_ from the JDK. V unlikely it would then go the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

The class `java.nio.StringCharBuffer` implements such a "view" on a substring without copying of the underlying char[] array of the String. It uses the `String.charAt` functions along with an internal offset (number of chars offset from the start of the String) in order to access the String array.

Unfortunately, it is package-private and not usable directly. The superclass `java.nio.CharBuffer` however is public, and you could implement your own implementation of a StringCharBuffer using the same approach that the `java.nio.StringCharBuffer` takes.

Note that if you do not do this and simply use `CharBuffer.wrap` as suggested by another answer you will still copy the array once.

Alternatively, you might just require a Stream of chars beginning from a certain index. In that case, you can use something like:

```
IntStream
  .range(start, str.length())
  .map(i -> str.charAt(i))
  ...
```

to get a Stream of chars. Note that this is different from doing `str.chars().skip(start)`, as the latter will actually advance the cursor by 1 `start` times.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dring {  // Double String
    double[] array;
    int length;
    int offset;
    // You probably want hash

    public Dring(double[] data) {
        array = new double[data.length];
        <copy from data to array using your favorite array copy method>
        length = data.length;
        offset = 0;
    }

    private Dring(int offsetParm, int lengthParm, double[] data) {
        array = data;
        length = lengthParm;
        offset = offsetParm
    } 

    public Dring subDring(int offsetParm, int lengthParm) {
         // Check parms
         return new Dring(offset + offsetParm, lengthParm, array);
    }

    public double doubleAt(int index) {
        // Check parm
        return array[offset + index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing here. Your solution involves basically a copy constructor of the original array.  Consider a linear algebra library backing array on order of 100's K to low millions of elements: avoiding a copy is pretty important.

Comment: @javadba - The `subDring` function does not copy the array.  And if you want the public constructor to not copy (trusting the array to be "immutable") you can easily do that.  The above code is the "moral equivalent" of the old non-copying String code.

Comment: @javadba - And, as the comments suggest, you should probably add parameter checks -- offsetParm positive and <= length, lengthParm <= length - offsetParm, index less than length.  (I haven't thought these through in detail.)

Comment: Just returned to this (7 yrs later). It looks good. I'd upvote it but already did (7 yrs back)! Those 2 downvotes are not explained.